# JButton won't display image

Tags: jbutton, imageicon

I am coding an app and doing my own custom window buttons as part of the design. However one thing has been bothering me.  I add an image to my jButton as such:

```
ImageIcon iExit = new ImageIcon("icons/exit.png");
System.out.print(iExit.getIconHeight());
base.setLayout(null);

winex = new PINGButton(iExit);
```

But I keep getting a -1 out in my test, so I clearly am not getting anything out. However it's not an issue with the file i do not get any exceptions when i added this bit of code for a test:

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("icons/exit.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("yep");
}
```

I ran it with different input to be sure but that file path is valid.

Here are some notes though. I turned off window decorations. I don't think that should effect it but something that should be stated. This button is placed statically in the window in a layout free jPanel. I also set custom color mouse over effects (there might be better ways to do this but atm this is what I'm using):

```
package main.java.com.hackathon.ping.objects;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class PINGButton extends JButton {

    private final Color defaultColor, hoverColor;

    /**
     * Keeping Eclipse Happy
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PINGButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        defaultColor = Color.WHITE;
        hoverColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        this.setBackground(defaultColor);
        addMouse();
        this.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.setIcon(getIcon());
    }

    public PINGButton(Icon i) {
        super(i);
        defaultColor = Color.WHITE;
        hoverColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        this.setBackground(defaultColor);
        addMouse();
        this.setBorderPainted(false);
    }

    public PINGButton(String text, Color main, Color hover) {
        super(text);

        defaultColor = main;
        hoverColor = hover;
        super.setBackground(defaultColor);
        addMouse();
        this.setBorderPainted(false);
    }

    private void addMouse() {
        super.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent a) { /* NOTHING */}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent a) {
                doMouseEnt();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent a) {
                doMouseEx();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {/* NOTHING */}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {/* NOTHING */}

        });
    }

    public void doMouseEx() {
        this.setBackground(defaultColor);
        this.setIcon(getIcon());
    }

    public void doMouseEnt() {
        this.setBackground(hoverColor);
        this.setIcon(getIcon());
    }
}
```

The image size is not an issue, I have tried the image and button adjusted to multiple sizes, and nothing seems to change.

Any ideas?

Comment: The constructor for `PINGButton` might be helpful here.

Comment: On a separate note, the lines that say `this.setIcon(getIcon())` are basically noops. Also, IIRC, you can add a `MouseAdapter` instead of a `MouseListener` and get default(read, empty) implementations for free, meaning you only have to add code for what you're actually implementing.

Comment: That was an attempt at a fix to this issue, but good to know that’s unnecessary.I thought of that, but eclipse wasn't happy with it at the time so I changed it to this. ATM this is fine for my purposes, but I will switch it. And I just realized why my attempt didn't work with the MouseAdapter.